# What's the standard way of displaying response from api using i18next?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

Is there a standard approach in i18next to properly select the intended texts returned by API based on the current selected language in the front-end?

Sample API response:

```
{
   "title":{
      "en":"Awesome",
      "de":"Fantastisch"
   }
}
```

CASE 1:

And the selected language in the front-end is `EN`.

What's the proper approach to select `title.en` and display it in a span for example?

CASE 2"

Selected language in front-end is `FR` or French.

But, there's no `fr` in the API response above, fallback should be `title.en`.

Comment: You can hardcode the necessary language fields into separate `en.json` and `fr.json`. Then use it to convert api responses accordingly. But it won't work if your api responses texts are changing dynamically which cannot be tracked by frontend i18n json files.

Comment: @KavinduVIndika can't bec the actual translations come from an API. And yes, expected that the API will change the response texts. Not the usual implementation where the language file is in the front-end.